# Gingerbread device throwing 411 on ajax requests

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am creating a phonegap app that needs to support android gingerbread.  The gingerbread device cannot successfully make ajax requests to the service API.  No other device appears to have this problem.  I always get back:

```
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

Some searching has indicated this is usually not a device-specific error. Here is the code I am using:

```
var addItemToList = function (itemId, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var address = appContext.createEndPointAddress("/List/" + itemId);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: address,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": appContext.getAuthHeader(),
            Accept:
                "application/site.error-ver1+json, application/site.success-ver1+json"
        }
    });
};
```

I am assuming it has to do with the request header formed by whatever browser gingerbread uses.  What should I do to repair the faulty header?

Comment: What happens if you try adding an empty `data` to the ajax call, (e.g. `data: {}, ...`)?

Comment: console.log(address); ....maybe your url is just too long

Comment: Currently creating a build with an empty data field.  Url address is probably not too long: (http://)localhost:61962/api/List/12345

Comment: Adding an empty data field did not come up with anything.  I will try it with an empty string instead.

Comment: matt, you led me down the right path, i will accept your answer if you want to submit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the issue.  Apparently, PUT requests are not normally created without a body.  Thus, adding the line:

```
data: "{}",
```

fixed the problem.